# How to include a user defined select list in a custom form

Tags: 7

I have a written a custom module that defines a block with a form in it.

Is it possible to allow the form to pull in a list of values that is defined by the user in drupal's cms?

If so how do I go about including that in the modules code?

Comment: Is your custom form made with Drupal's Form API? Also how is the select list defined, that you want to use?

Comment: yes it's possible - how depends on the setup for the form and what information you want to pull into the list. In general, search for how to add to a select list with code - there are dozens, perhaps hundreds of tutorials out there

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it all working using Taxonomies.